# install gitlab on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, installation, gitlab

I am trying to install gitlab on ubuntu 18.04. 
I follow the steps on 
https://about.gitlab.com/install/#ubuntu

In the second step, I write: 
curl https:
//packages.gitlab.com/install/repositories/gitlab/gitlab-ee/script.deb.sh | sudo bash

My terminal says:
Unable to install curl! Your base system has a problem; please check your default OS's package repositories because curl should work.
Repository installation aborted.

I don't fix the error.

Answer (score 0):

The stated error message says curl could not be found and could also not be installed by the script. Try the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install curl
```

If the installation was successful try to run the script again. If not there should be an error message of the installation.

Comment: I would appreciate if you mark my answer as correct.